My app run in chrome it was not working in mobile or emulator . how can i solve it
My app run in chrome it was not working in mobile or emulator . how can i solve it
i need solve it . i was facing this issues last 2 days in my flutter app . if  you know how to solve it tell me .
send you are answer to me
